# How to load dataset of wav audios into TensorFlow

Tags: python, audio, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm trying to train a standard fully-connected neural network(a.k.a. multilayer perceptron) with TensorFlow. I'm following a tutorial where a similar neural network is trained with the MNIST dataset of handwritten digits (http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/).

However, TensorFlow offers some built-in operations, I can't really replicate.

Ex:
To load the data, it calls the following function:

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data    
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)
```

or to load the next batch from the data, it calls the following function:

```
batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
```

Does anyone know any similar implementation for audio data? I want the input to be the raw data of the wav files. I have my data structured in this way:

```
data/
    train/
       up/
         ...
       down/
         ...
       ...
     test/
       up/
         ...
       down/
         ...
       ...

     validate/
       up/
         ...
       down/
         ...
       ...
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have a peek at [DCASE](http://dcase.community/), there is a healthy community.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in operation specific for importing audio-data.

However, you can take a look at [this](https://www.kaggle.com/alexozerin/end-to-end-baseline-tf-estimator-lb-0-72) implementation as a starting point.

You can first generate a list of your audio files using

```
def load_data(data_dir):
    """ Return 2 lists of tuples:
    [(class_id, user_id, path), ...] for train
    [(class_id, user_id, path), ...] for validation
    """
    # Just a simple regexp for paths with three groups:
    # prefix, label, user_id
    pattern = re.compile("(.+\/)?(\w+)\/([^_]+)_.+wav")
    all_files = glob(os.path.join(data_dir, 'train/audio/*/*wav'))

    with open(os.path.join(data_dir, 'train/validation_list.txt'), 'r') as fin:
        validation_files = fin.readlines()
    valset = set()
    for entry in validation_files:
        r = re.match(pattern, entry)
        if r:
            valset.add(r.group(3))
```

and then create a generator function to feed the files to your Tensorflow model:

```
def data_generator(data, params, mode='train'):
    def generator():
        if mode == 'train':
            np.random.shuffle(data)
        # Feel free to add any augmentation
        for (label_id, uid, fname) in data:
            try:
                _, wav = wavfile.read(fname)
                wav = wav.astype(np.float32) / np.iinfo(np.int16).max

                L = 16000  # be aware, some files are shorter than 1 sec!
                if len(wav) < L:
                    continue
                # let's generate more silence!
                samples_per_file = 1 if label_id != name2id['silence'] else 20
                for _ in range(samples_per_file):
                    if len(wav) > L:
                        beg = np.random.randint(0, len(wav) - L)
                    else:
                        beg = 0
                    yield dict(
                        target=np.int32(label_id),
                        wav=wav[beg: beg + L],
                    )
            except Exception as err:
                print(err, label_id, uid, fname)

    return generator
```